# Can you customize the plot generated from the MATLAB function 'ecdf'?

Tags: matlab, plot, ecdf

I find that I can easily customize when I use the 'plot' function, but I cannot seem to do the same things with the 'ecdf' function.  Are you able to customize the way ecdf is displayed?  Mainly, I would like the linewidth to be thicker so people can trace it easily (it is hard to see on the right hand side of my plot where it coincides with the border of the plot).  Thank you!

```
ecdf(asset1)
title("Empirical Distribution Function of Asset Fluctuations")
xlabel("Value of Fluctuations")
ylabel("P(X<=x)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, get current plot using `h = get(gca,'children')`
- Then customize the plot using ***set*** helper, like  `set(h,'LineWidth',3)`

---

**Illustration**

```
rng('default')

% Given data
R = wblrnd(100,2,100,1);

ecdf(R,'Function','survivor','Alpha',0.05,'Bounds','on');

% Get plotted lines, 3 in total
h = get(gca,'children');


% Customize First line 
set(h(1),'LineWidth',3, 'color', 'red', 'LineStyle', '-');

% Customize second line 
set(h(2),'LineWidth',15, 'color', 'blue', 'LineStyle', '-');

% Customize third line 
set(h(3),'LineWidth',8, 'color', 'green', 'Marker', '+', 'LineStyle', '-');

% axes label
xlabel('Xlabel', 'color', 'red')
ylabel('Ylabel', 'color', 'red')
xticklabels({'X1'; 'X2'; 'X3';'X4'; 'X5'})
yticklabels({'Y1'; 'Y2'; 'Y3';'Y4'; 'Y5'; 'Y6'; 'Y7'; 'Y8';'Y9'; 'Y10'})
% display ylabel horizontally
hYLabel = get(gca,'YLabel');
set(hYLabel,'rotation',0,'VerticalAlignment','middle',  'HorizontalAlignment','right')


% Customizing axes /Borders/ labels 
set(gca,'XGrid','on', 'YGrid', 'on', 'Fontsize', 20,'linewidth', 5);


% legend
[~,b] = legend([h(1) h(2) h(3)],{'Line 1 ','Line 2', 'Line 3'}, 'FontSize',30);
set(findobj(b,'-property','MarkerSize'),'MarkerSize',30);

title('Customized ecdf','color', 'red', 'fontSize', 30)
```

---

> ## *Default ecdf*

[image]

---

> ## *Customized ecdf*

[image]